# Event listener outside of Shadow DOM won't bind to elements inside of Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadow-dom

I have an Angular web component installed on my site. It uses Shadow DOM so it's super fast (which it has to be in my case).

On my site I also have a shortcut on <kbd>h</kbd> which opens up a popup that displays some helpful information. It's a must that this <kbd>h</kbd> keybinding stays as it is. Example code of how it was implemented can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/js1edv37/

It's a simple event listener that listens on `document`:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {

}
```

However, this also gets triggered when my web component has focused `textarea` or `input` elements. This happens because it uses Shadow DOM, which a script from the outside cannot access.

You can test it by pressing <kbd>h</kbd> on the keyboard inside and outside of the `input` and `textarea` elements.

Is there a way to let my script from outside of the Shadow DOM web component, still listen for the `keyup` event, but make it listen for *all* elements on the page? Even the ones inside the Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Web Component, get the input element with a `querySelector()` call on the `shadowRoot` property:

```
let textareainshadow = div.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'textarea' )
```

Then listen to the `keyup` event and stop its propagation with the help of the `stopImmediatePropagation()` method.

```
textareainshadow.addEventListener( 'keyup' , ev => {
    console.log( 'caught', ev.type )
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7mkrxh25/1/

Comment: I do not have access to the code that generates the shadow DOM. It's all done via Angular, so this wouldn't work. I'm setting up a StackBlitz to demonstate my problem.

Comment: I you can get the reference (`ref`) to the angular web component you should be able to access its shadow dom via `ref.shadowRoot`. Or from iniside the angular code: `this.shadowRoot`.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, because I cannot access the reference. I wouldn't know how. You can see this in a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webcomponent-polyfill-w2xff4?file=src%2Findex.html - `index.html` contains the web component (Shadow DOM) and also the textarea. How would you solve it?

Comment: Aaaah I see how, now. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you save the reference to the shadow root you can always access it's children as search on those

```js
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    let focusedInputs = $("input:focus, textarea:focus").length + $(shadow).children("input:focus, textarea:focus").length;

    if (focusedInputs > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 72) {
        trigger();
    }
});

function trigger() {
    alert("If this was triggered, everything is perfectly fine");
}

let div = document.querySelector("div");
let shadow = div.createShadowRoot();
shadow.innerHTML = "<textarea>This shouldn't fail</textarea>";
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
}

input {
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Some stuff here</textarea>
<br />
<input type="text" value="Some more text here" />

<br />
<br />

<h1>Shadow DOM element WON'T fail now :)</h1>

<div></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgbp8jzk/)

Comment: I do not have a reference to the shadow root. My Shadow DOM is contained inside of an Angular web component. This does not work, unfortunately. All because of encapsulation. Maybe I phrased my question the wrong way.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Nope, it's just me being dense and not reading your question thoroughly, you did say "This happens because it uses Shadow DOM, which a script from the outside cannot access."

Comment: Exactly haha. I would love to say "if my web component is on this page, simply ignore the keyup/return true". However, that won't work, because my web component fills up about 75% of the page. I guess there aren't really anything I can do :(